# How can I perform many-to-many insert using MySQL an PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many MySQL database with three tables entry, tag, and entry_tag. 
entry table has id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT and entry TEXT columns
tag table has id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRMARY KEY and tag VARCHAR(15) columns
entry_tag is a mapping tables between entry and tag, and has entry_id INT and tag_id INT, entry_id and tag_id creates PRIMARY KEY.

Now, I would like to INSERT entry.title and entry.entry and related tags tag.tag to the database and respective tables. I would also like to INSERT appropriate mapping information into entry_tag table. Could anyone tell me how can I possible do it? I am using PHP. How can I get the entry.id and tag.id and link them together in the mapping table?

I have:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO entry SET
    title = '$title',
    entry = '$entry'";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql_query)) {
    $error = 'Error adding submitted entry.';
    include 'includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
}

$sql_query = "INSERT INTO tag SET
    tag = '$tag'";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql_query)) {
    $error = 'Error adding submitted entry.';
    include 'includes/error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

Now, I would like to perform:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO entry_tag SET
    entry_id = '$entry.id',
    tag_id = '$tag.id'";
```

But I stuck on getting the right $entry.id and $tag.id.

Comment: What do you have so far/What have you tried/What's not working/Show your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_insert_id()` to capture the ID of the last insert

Comment: thank you, I just wonder, what if I am inserting more than one tag? For example running a loop over all submitted tags that are not in the database yet? I guess I should submit one tag and immediately followed by insert into entry_tag, right?

Comment: either that or save all created IDs in an array and use them later

Comment: thank you, $entryid = mysqli_insert_id($link); does the trick